# Objective C formatting for blogging

Tags: blogs

I blog on Wordpress, is there any tool to upload the Objective C code in a  formatted manner to my blog. I googled to find more on this..but was not of much help.

Comment: Belongs on the WordPress SE Public Beta. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Wordpress for iOS](http://ios.wordpress.org/development/). The Wordpress app is open source, so you can rummage through the code.

Comment: +1 If you want to use memory leaks, evil UIs, crashes and other crap from this app it's worth to take a look in its code. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking about formatting the code in blog posts? If so you can use a syntex highlihging library like [syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/).

**Edit**: There is also a wordpress plugin that will do syntex highligting: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax highlighter plugins for Wordpress, but not all of them support Objective-C. I just found one that does: The name is "Auto SyntaxHighlighter".

The [website of the plugin](https://www.akii.org/auto-syntaxhighlighter.html) doesn't mention Objective-C, but the plugin does.

When you write your article in the visual editor in Wordpress, there will be an icon for adding source code. There you can choose the language (e. g. "Objective-C").

In the visual editor, you cannot see all the nice bells and whistles of the added source code, but if you click "preview", you will see the nice syntax highlighting, etc.